# ColdFusion: Trying to query database in CFScript

Tags: coldfusion

My boss wants me to use cfscript instead of tags for database interaction. Does anybody know of any good tutorials? I bought the Adobe ColdFusion application development book, vol 2.  But it does not have much on scripting.  I did google and found [this site](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/10/10/query-object-in-cfscript), but it did not explain much.

Does any body know of any good tutorials on accessing the data base in CFScript?

Basically I have to convert the following to using CFScript:

```
<cfquery name="drafts" datasource="ICEchat">
    SELECT * from Messages where IsTemp=1 and LinkA=#FORM.LinkA# and LinkB=#FORM.LinkA#
</cfquery>
<cfif drafts.recordcount GT '0'>
    <cfquery name="Attachments" datasource="ICEchat">
        SELECT * FROM Attachments where id=2
    </cfquery>
    { Message:"<cfoutput query="drafts">#Message#</cfoutput>", Attachments:[<cfoutput query="attachments">
        "#url#"<cfif attachments.currentRow LT attachments.recordcount>,</cfif>
    </cfoutput>]}
<cfelse>
    <cfquery name="addrecord" datasource="ICEchat">
        INSERT INTO Messages 
        VALUES(1,1,' ',1)
    </cfquery>
    { Message:"NA", Attachments:[]}
</cfif>
```

Comment: You're right, Jake, that it was pretty awful. But it took me less than a minute to fix it. Which is more constructive: Complaining or fixing it?

Comment: Well, here is the official documentation. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html

Comment: @AdamTuttle you're right, of course.  More virtue to be found in overlooking such things.

Comment: Hi,thank you for the link, Guess I need to look at my typing more,

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion. The current version, 2016, has `queryExecute()` which a very clean syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [4th link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116230402/http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2009/7/16/ColdFusion-9--CFScript-Examples--QUERY--Query-Param) on google for "cfscript query tutorial":

```
<CFSCRIPT>
    myQry = new Query(); // new query object     
    myQry.setSQL("select bookid, title, genre from app.books where bookid = :bookid"); //set query
    myQry.addParam(name="bookid",value="5",CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER"); // add query param
    qryRes = myQry.execute(); // execute query
    writedump(qryRes.getResult().recordcount, true); // get resultcount
    writedump(qryRes.getResult(), false); // dump result
    writeoutput('<BR>');
</CFSCRIPT>
```

That ought to tell you everything you need to know.

Also, you *really* should not be creating JSON manually, no matter how simple it is. Use `serializeJson()`.

Comment: Hi can query and execute the Query object, but when I try to get information about the equerry, ie drafts.record count or drafts.Messag[0], i get a error saying drafts.record count define or drafts.Messag[0] any idear?

Comment: Hi,Ok i was not getting the info off the Result object.  Thank you for your ost it gave me enough enfo to finish my project :)

Comment: You're putting a lot of faith in serializeJson() Adam :)

Comment: Mike, it's not perfect (if you have trouble, I'd suggest JSONUtil: http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/) but building it by hand is asking for trouble. Especially as the requirements change over time and it becomes more and more complex.

Comment: I think adobe should just fix serializeJSON, so devs dont ever have to even consider manually writing their json, its a clear indicator somethings not right

Answer (score 7):

Didn't test this, but this should do it.

```
<cfscript>
   local.drafts = new Query();
   local.drafts.setDatasource("ICEchat");
   local.drafts.addParam(name="linkA", value="#form.linkA#", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR");
   local.drafts.addParam(name="linkB", value="#form.linkB#", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR");
   local.drafts.setSQL("SELECT * from Messages where IsTemp=1 and LinkA = :linkA and LinkB = :linkA");
   local.drafts.execute().getResult();

   if (local.drafts.recordcount GT 0) {
      local.attachments = new Query();
      local.attachments.setDatasource("ICEchat");
      local.attachments.setSQL("SELECT * FROM Attachments where id=2");
      local.attachments.execute().getResult();
      WriteOutput("{ Message: ");
      for (i=1; i LTE local.drafts.recordcount; i=i+1) {
         WriteOutput(local.drafts.message[i]);
      }
      WriteOutput(", Attachments: ");
      for (i=1; i LTE local.attachments.recordcount; i=i+1) {
         WriteOutput(local.drafts.url[i]);
         if (i LT local.attachments.recordcount) {
            WriteOutput(", ");
         }
      }
      WriteOutput("}");
   } else {
      local.q = new Query();
      local.q.setDatasource("ICEchat");
      local.q.setSQL("INSERT INTO Messages VALUES(1,1,' ',1)");
      local.q.execute();
      WriteOutput("{ Message:"NA", Attachments:[]}");
   }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Nl can query and execute the Query object, but when I try to get information about the equerry, ie drafts.record count or drafts.Messag[0], i get a error saying drafts.record count define

Answer (score -3):

I have been searching for a solution for the same error. I get not defined errors or construct errors. Have been chatting with Ray Camden for the past day, but everything he has suggested is not doing what I need either. I have been working on a website conversion from the standard CF tags to cfscript.

Ray suggested that the .execute(); is what pulls the recordcount and suggested this is all was needed: x=queryExecute(); would fetch the recordcount, with (x) being the query. He suggested not to use getPrefix(); but I read that the .getPrefix(); is what pulls the recordcount. He is experienced I am sure you know Ray Camden, but I keep getting the same error no matter what I try doing inside of my code.

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow uses a Q&A format (question and answer). This section is only for "answers". If you think you have found a different solution than the ones already suggested, please rephrase the above into the form of an "answer". Otherwise, it may be deleted as a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) rather than an "answer" to the question asked.